# cell value condition for loop OpenPyxl /'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'/

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

```
wb = load_workbook(example.xlsx)
ws = wb.active
for i in ws:
    if i != Date_COFTR:
        ws.append([Date_COFTR])
        wb.save(example.xlsx)
```

I am trying to append a date (the actual date value is assigned to the 'Date_COFTR' variable that has been webscraped and turned into one string) to my excel sheet. The code above is an attempt of me trying to make a condition that only if the value of 'Date_COFTR' is not already in the excel sheet, then append it. Otherwise, everytime I run this code the date will replicate which is not preferred. The variable 'Date_COFTR' updates weekly which is why I have webscraped it.

when I append the variable without the (failed) condition, it works but as mentioned it just replicates the date everytime i run the script.

When I try this I get the error /'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'/ or it just doesn't do anything to the excel sheet without errors.

Comment: The code is incomplete as is the traceback which cannot come from this code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code 'i' will be a tuple of row1 cells in the sheet covering the column range of used cells. The statement

```
if i != Date_COFTR:
```

will always be True since Date_COFTR I expect is a string and will never match.

Where are you wanting to check for the existence of 'Date_COFTR'? From your line

```
ws.append([Date_COFTR])
```

it seems you add 'Date_COFTR' to the next from last used row on the sheet. Therefore it would seem this is the cell you want to check i.e. the last used row in column A.
Or do you mean to check all used cells in the sheet?

The following code may help.
It gets the maximum used row and column to use as a cell range then if you are just looking for the last append made you can use this line only

```
ws.cell(row=max_range_row, column=1).value
```

to compare against Date_COFTR.

If you are checking all used cells then use the for loop

```
...
max_range_row = ws.max_row
max_range_col = ws.max_column

# This line will provide the value of the last ws.append cell
last_append = ws.cell(row=max_range_row, column=1).value
if last_append != Date_COFTR:
    ws.append([Date_COFTR])

# This code will get the value of each cell in the range of used cells
for row in range(1, max_range_row + 1):
    for col in range(1, max_range_col + 1):
        cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
        cell_value = cell.value
        if cell_value != Date_COFTR:
            # Append Date_COFTR to sheet? see notes below
wb.save(example.xlsx)
```

If check all cells in the range is what you need then you probably don't want to append Date_COFTR for each cell that does not have Date_COFTR otherwise you'd have numerous appends so you would either note that there is a match and append once when the loop finishes or 
do append and exit the loop.
You should also have the workbook save one of the last statements and not part of the loop (see indention used in example), should only need to save once at the end.